# InfluxDB [Error: No host available]

Tags: node.js, influxdb

I am just trying out InfluxDB. I am using the modified example from their docs to generate some random test data but when I run it with node it says [Error: No host available]. I tried to connect to InfluxDB via curl and web console both of them work so I am not sure where it is failing.

I just installed influxdb and influx npm so there are the latest version.

```js
var influxdb = require('influx');
client = new influxdb.InfluxDB('localhost',8086, 'root', 'root', 'tempdb');

// start time of 24 hours ago
var backMilliseconds = 86000 * 1000;
var startTime = new Date() - backMilliseconds;
var timeInterval = 60 * 1000;
var eventTypes = ["click", "view", "post", "comment"];

var cpuSeries = {
  name:    "cpu_idle",
  columns: ["time", "value", "hostName"],
  points:  []
};

var eventSeries = {
  name:    "customer_events",
  columns: ["time", "customerId", "type"],
  points:  []
};

for (i = 0; i < backMilliseconds; i += timeInterval) {
  // generate fake cpu idle host values
  var hostName = "server" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var value = Math.random() * 100;
  var pointValues = [startTime + i, value, hostName];
  cpuSeries.points.push(pointValues);

  // generate some fake customer events
  for (j = 0; j < Math.random() * 10; j += 1) {
    var customerId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    var eventTypeIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 % 4);
    var eventValues = [startTime + i, customerId, eventTypes[eventTypeIndex]];
    eventSeries.points.push(eventValues);
  }
}

client.writeSeries([cpuSeries, eventSeries],{},function(err){
    if(err) {
        console.log("Cannot write data",err);
    }
});
```